# SSRS 2005 report page orientation with subreports

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a report which is composed of several subreports. I need to render some of the reports as landscape and others as portrait. SSRS 2005 doesnt appear to support this behavior. Does anyone know if it is possible to get this behavior without having to hand roll a "report packager"?

To be clear, the client wants to print one report which is composed of several subreports. Some of the subreports are landscape and some are portrait. The main report appears to override the page orientation of the subreports.

Comment: why was this downvoted? It seems to me like a very relevant question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be constrained by the page settings on the main report.

The best bet is to create a report packager as you mentioned.  I've used the library [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to do this on a project once.  It didn't take much work to get it to work and it functioned marvelously.

Comment: Since the reports are already created in SSRS, I'm building a custom control that wraps the print review control and presenting a report viewer style UI that gives the users a packaged report view.
SSRS can deliver each report as a TIFF document which I will merge together.

Comment: About the same effect as I suggested using TIFF instead of PDF.